# C#: DataContractSerializer and different streams

Tags: c#, stream, datacontractserializer

I'd like to use `DataContractSerializer` and I'm confused about the `Stream` parameter in its `WriteObject` method - I see that I can use either `MemoryStream` or `XmlWriter`. I'd like to know:

- How is the serialization affected by the stream selection? Does it affect the size of the object?
- When using `MemoryStream`, do I always get a binary object?

Those questions might be basic, but I've been googling and can't find clear answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataContractSerializer` is inherently an *xml-based* serializer. If you pass a `Stream`, it will construct an `XmlWriter` (specifically, an `XmlDictionaryWriter`) that wraps the stream, and then the core serialization code writes to the `XmlWriter`.

> How is the serialization affected by the stream selection? Does it affect the size of the object?

Using different `Stream` instances doesn't affect what happens internally, but
there can  be *slight* differences here compared to passing in an `XmlWriter`, depending on what the *encoding* is. If you pass a `Stream`, then `DataContractSerializer` uses UTF-8; but if you pass it an `XmlWriter` you can specify different encodings.

> When using `MemoryStream`, do I always get a binary object?

`MemoryStream` is a wrapper over a `byte[]`, and yes: once you've called `.ToArray()` afterwards you have just binary. However, it is binary that *also* happens to be xml. It can be both.

If you want serialization that is *actually* binary (meaning: fundamentally a binary serialization format, rather than xml / json / csv / etc), then maybe consider something like protobuf-net.

Comment: Thanks :)
I want to serialize an object in order to save it in the DB (I'm not sure I want normalization). Is there a rule of thumb regarding when to use binary format?
Is there any decompression involved in the serialization?
How can I see the `MemoryStream`'s xml output?

Comment: @Noich to see the contents of a memory stream as xml, just use something like `string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)ms.Length);`. protobuf-net does not apply *compression* (as in: gzip, deflate etc) - however, it is very efficient in terms of what it stores, and is usually *significantly* smaller. If you care about bandwidth and/or storage, but don't need human readable, then it would be a reasonable choice.

Answer (score 1):

As Marc says, if you you use the overload of `WriteObject` which takes a `Stream`, then the bytes written to the stream by the `DataContractSerializer` will comprise the UTF-8 encoded text of an XML Document, regardless of the type of `Stream` instance passed in. If the instance is a `MemoryStream`, you end up with an in-memory array of bytes (because that's what a MemoryStream is), but those bytes comprise UTF-8 encoded XML text - which would not normally be described as a binary representation.

If you use the overload of `WriteObject` which takes an `XmlWriter`, what you end up with is entirely determined by what type your `XmlWriter` is, and how it has been initialised. As far as the `DataContractSerializer` is concerned, it will call the methods of the `XmlWriter` in the appropriate pattern to describe an XML Infoset representing the state of your object. How that Infoset is encoded depends on the implementation of the `XmlWriter`.

If you had specialised requirements, and were particularly masochistic, you could implement your own custom `XmlWriter` to do any sort of encoding, compressing, encrypting, whatever took your fancy. Or you could pass an `XmlTextWriter`, which will give you a text encoding of the Infoset (like the Stream overload), but with more options for controlling the character encoding and the text formatting. More usually you will pass a `XmlDictionaryWriter`, and then you have various options for the encoding depending on how you create it.

These options include WCF's own binary encoding of XML Infosets: to get that you create the instance with `XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter`. Since the WCF team invested a good deal of effort into designing an efficient binary representation in order to meet WCF's performance targets, you'll be hard pressed, I imagine, to come up with a better option provided that you can be sure that the resulting serialized objects will only ever need to be deserialized by .NET code. If you need a public-standards-based binary representation you might instead consider the `MTOM` flavour of `XmlDictionaryWriter`.